# Assert Equalsusing streams different type of list with multiple fields

Tags: java, java-stream

```
public class OrdersDto implements java.io.Serializable {
    /** Id **/
    private Long screening;
    private Long category;
    private TestMastDto testMast;
    /** getters & setters/ constructor */
}

public class TestMastDto implements java.io.Serializable {
    /** Id **/
    private Long testId;    
    /** getters & setters/ constructor */
}
```

There is another POJO format

```
public class ReviewMedicalConfigDto implements Serializable {
    /** Id **/
    private Long jobCategoryId;
    private Long screeningTypeId;
    private Long testId;
}
```

I have a `List<OrdersDto>  and a List<ReviewMedicalConfigDto>`, how can I compare testId, screeningTypeId, jobCategoryId in lists of different types using java streams or any other efficient way in java

Tried this for only testId which gives class cast exception

```
 boolean isConfigTest = orders.stream().map(orObj -> orObj.getTestMast().getTestId())
                     .collect(Collectors.toList()).equals(reviewMedicalConfigDtos.stream().map( rmObj -> rmObj.getTestId() ));
```

Exception java.lang.ClassCastException: om.gov.moh.services.dto.ReviewMedicalStatusDto cannot be cast to om.gov.moh.services.dto.OrdersDto

Comment: "...List and a List" you question is missing some details, not clear IMO. Do you mean `List<ReviewMedicalConfigDto>` etc?

Comment: When you ask about an exception, post the complete exception stack trace, always. And post the relevant code: there is no cast at all n what you posted, so the exception is probably unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

The general pattern is

```
boolean match = list1.size() == list2.size() &&
    IntStream.range(0, list1.size()).allMatch( index -> {
        FirstType  a = list1.get(index);
        SecondType b = list2.get(index);
        return Objects.equals(a.getProperty1(), b.getProperty1())
            && Objects.equals(a.getProperty2(), b.getProperty2())
            && Objects.equals(a.getProperty3(), b.getProperty3());
    });
```

though an ordinary loop might be simpler.

For properties of primitive type, you might replace `Objects.equals(a.getPropertyX(), b.getPropertyX())` with `a.getPropertyX() == b.getPropertyX()`…